Django Graph API Timeout while validating endpoint on Azure / AWS
I have been struggling for the past couple of days with setting up a webhook for outlook via the Graph API of microsoft. Initially, I hosted my application locally and exposed it to the internet with ngrok. Connecting to the Graph API worked well. However, when I moved my application to the cloud. I noticed that each time I tried to setup the Graph API webhook for outlook, I received a timeout error. I checked my Azure endpoint with:
curl -X POST https://db.chainfill.bluewaterfall.nl/email-integration/emails?validationToken=someToken -H "Accept: text/plain" -v
and everything worked fine, yielding a 200 Ok response. I also tracked the incomming headers for my application on Azure. When I make a subscription request, the entire backend seems non responsive, as if the graph API request blocks the entire server.
Tim out error:
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): graph.microsoft.com:443 https://graph.microsoft.com:443 "POST /v1.0/subscriptions HTTP/1.1" 400 None Graph API Error: {'error': {'code': 'ValidationError', 'message': 'Subscription validation request timed out.', 'innerError': {'date': '2024-05-14T16:12:13', 'request-id': 'eb76a2e1-95c7-439c-aaca-6efaf031723d', 'client-request-id': 'eb76a2e1-95c7-439c-aaca-6efaf031723d'}}}
Right afte receiving the time out error:
Response for /email-integration/subscription with headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Vary': 'Accept, origin', 'Allow': 'POST, OPTIONS', 'X-Frame-Options': 'DENY', 'Content-Length': '42', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Referrer-Policy': 'same-origin', 'Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy': 'same-origin'} 
Response Status Code: 200 Response Content Type: application/json Incoming request at /email-integration/emails with headers: {'Host': 'db.chainfill.bluewaterfall.nl', 'X-Real-Ip': '137.135.11.116', 'X-Forwarded-For': '137.135.11.116', 'X-Forwarded-Proto': 'https', 'Connection': 'close', 'Content-Length': '0', 'Client-Request-Id': 'eb76a2e1-95c7-439c-aaca-6efaf031723d', 'Accept': 'text/plain', 'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'}
Request Path: /email-integration/emails
Request Method: POST
Request Query Params: <QueryDict: {'validationToken': ['Validation: Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: eb76a2e1-95c7-439c-aaca-6efaf031723d']}>
Accept Headers: text/plain Request URL: https://db.chainfill.bluewaterfall.nl/email-integration/emails?validationToken=Validation%3a+Testing+client+application+reachability+for+subscription+Request-Id%3a+eb76a2e1-95c7-439c-aaca-6efaf031723d
validation_token Validation: Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: eb76a2e1-95c7-439c-aaca-6efaf031723d
Received validation token Response for /email-integration/emails with headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/plain', 'X-Frame-Options': 'DENY', 'Content-Length': '117', 'Vary': 'origin', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Referrer-Policy': 'same-origin', 'Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy': 'same-origin'}
Response Status Code: 200 Response Content Type: text/plain
This is the piece of the code that receives the validation post message from graph api:
Python
`@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
class GetMailsFromOutlookView(View):
"""Fetches an email from outlook when a new email is received"""
queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
# Need to secure this route still

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    global last_processed
    debounce_period = 30
    try:
        logging.debug(f'Request URL: {request.build_absolute_uri()}')
        # Retrieve the validation token from the query parameters
        validation_token = request.GET.get('validationToken')
        logging.debug(f'validation_token {validation_token}')
        if validation_token:
            logging.debug('Received validation token')
            # Check the Accept header and adjust the content type of the response accordingly
            accept_header = request.headers.get('Accept', 'text/plain')  # Default to text/plain if not specified
            if 'text/plain' in accept_header:
                return HttpResponse(validation_token, content_type="text/plain", status=200)
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Unsupported media type", status=415)`

I have also tried hosting on aws, but the same problem arrised. The Vm that I'm running is: Standard B2ms (2 vcpus, 8 GiB memory). If somebody encountered a similar problem or knows some steps forward that I can take, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot!
Best regards,
Yorick
Backend:

Django

Tried:

Hosting on Azure
Hosting on AWS
Different endpoint configurations

Expected:

resolve the timeout error


For anyone interested in this problem. The bug had to do specifically with how the application was hosted on Azure.
It ended up having to do with the fact that the Django backend application only spawned 1 thread (Django works with threads instead of async operations). While making a request from graph api to our endpoint, the application was still busy configuring graph api itself, making the endpoint unavailable for reach. This also explains why, right after the request to our endpoint failed and the connection to graph api was lost, the original request went through

So instead of running:
gunicorn project.asgi --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
run with multiple workers and threads:
gunicorn project.asgi -w 4 --threads 6 --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
